# Microsoft Office Excel Add-In No Longer passing Customer data

Tags: excel, contacts, excel-addins

We've got a Excel add-in connected to our CRM. It uses the HTTPS callback to add contacts to our database. About 1 week ago, the contacts started being inserted with undefined data.

Looking into this, the POST data passed from Microsoft should include the following, but the userDetails is now blank. Even on the website, there is a ability to Validate and test the callback, that callback is no longer providing the data described in the documentation.

Is anyone aware of something that might've changed here?

[image]

[image]